# Single diode in automotive 40 W DC circuit as reverse polarity protection

Tags: diodes

I'm replacing an old controller of a heated grip for motorcycles for some of my friends with a 555 timer PWM circuit and a MOSFET and wanted to add some reverse polarity protection so that they can't kill it when they add and remove it from their bikes each cycling season (the cables are the same color and not labeled. Changing the cable color would be the easiest fix but I wouldn't learn anything from that).

I have never used a diode with this high a wattage as it is around 36-40 W initially, somewhere between 12 V and 15 V DC. As I only used diodes in microcontoller environments of 3.3 V and 5 V I thought there was no difference in picking a diode, but reading datasheets on DigiKey and LCSC made me think I have missed something, as diodes with higher average current handling seem rare.

As most datasheets are filled with data for AC usage I'd also have to take an educated guess on how it would perform under a DC source and load (average current × 2 or 3?).

Should I stick with the simple one-diode idea or should I switch to a MOSFET switched solution in case it gets wired the wrong way around? A rectifier could also do but that would be the same datasheet issue. A fuse would probably also be a good addition to avoid magic component smoke.

[image: simple case diagram]

Comment: Why would a diode save it? Why would it become damaged without the diode? A fuse is used to protect cabling infrastructure and not components usually.

Comment: I'd think a diode would save it as it should resist current in the wrong direction.
The fuse idea would be together with another diode to blow if there is current in the wrong direction.

Comment: What is this controller?  Could we see a photo?  Might be that the polarity doesn't matter.

Comment: The controller ain't physical yet but as it contains a 555 timer circuit polarity matters. Without it i would totally agree as resistors and switches don't care about directions.

Comment: _"it contains a 555 timer circuit"_ - Please put that information in the question, including schematic showing how it controls the heater.

Comment: You might consider using a bridge rectifier - these are available with high current ratings and will allow the device to work whichever way it’s connected.  The downside is that you’ll have 2 diode drops, but perhaps you can deposit the excess heat into the handlebars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with the worst case current: heater on high (40 W) and lowest cranking voltage (~10 V) for a nice round 4 A.  Now for your diode ratings: some diodes will give DC values on their datasheets (see page 3 of: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/348/ROHMS24573_1-2561214.pdf), and you can see that the DC current is a bit higher than the average rectified current.  If your diode doesn't have a DC curve, and you don't want to find one that does, I would start with 4 A average rectified and give yourself a minimum 50% buffer, so as an example something like this: https://www.panjit.com.tw/upload/datasheet/SBM845LSS.pdf (Note that the buffer is the "engineering buffer" to avoid running your components at maximum ratings and assumes that, in the absence of more favorable data from the manufacturer, the DC and average rectified current values are the same.)

Now, let's do a bit of math to make sure the diode isn't going to burn up.  The max forward voltage (VF) is 500 mV so 4 A makes 2 W of heat.  The thermal resistance from the junction to ambient (RΦJA) is 40 C/W, which means that the junction will heat up 80 C above ambient.  The maximum junction temperature (TJ) is 150 C, so the maximum ambient temperature is the difference, 70 C.  Seeing as the heater will probably not be on if the temperature is much above 15 C, I don't envision this being a problem; just don't mount the diode somewhere that gets hot from the engine or exhaust.

As always, it's a good idea to take a look at manufacturer white papers/app notes to see if they have any insights and there is an excellent one here: https://www.nexperia.com/applications/interactive-app-notes/IAN50001_automotive-reverse-battery-protection.html

Comment: Thanks. This confirmed my guesses and also my fear of a seriously hot component. But that's manageable.

Answer (score 2):

I would not bother, it is a electric heater is a resistive load which is not polarity sensitive. If you have something else then I would use a P-Channel MOSFET as it will run a lot cooler with less power loss. This is because there will be a much lower voltage drop across it.

Comment: The only thing i'd like to protect is a 555 timer circuit which should provide a pwm signal for a MOSFET to regulate the heaters. But the MOSFET idea could also be considered. Thanks